# indexOf devuelve -1

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy realizando el siguiente script para crear una lista desplegable dependiente.

```
  function onEdit() {
  var archivo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojadatos = archivo. getSheetByName("Presupuesto");
  var rubro = hojadatos.getActiveCell().getValues();
  var filctiva = hojadatos.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var columactiva = hojadatos.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var hojatablavd = archivo.getSheetByName ("TablasVD");
  var rubros = hojatablavd.getRange(1,1,1,28).getValues();
  var indice = rubros[0].indexOf(rubro);
  Logger.log (rubro);
  Logger.log (rubros);
  Logger.log(indice);

if (filctiva>14 && columnactiva==3){
  hojadatos.getRange('D15').setValue(5);
  }

  
  
}
```

Cuando intento encontrar la columna en la que se encuentra el rubro "Tareas_Preliminares" por medio del indexOf me devuelve el valor -1 y como ven aparece en el rango rubros . No entiendo por que no lo encuentra

```
Registro de ejecución
16:33:09 Aviso Se ha iniciado la ejecución 16:33:09 Información [[Tareas_Preliminares]] 
16:33:09 Información [[Tareas_Preliminares, Estructura, Albañileria, Plomeria, Gasista Matriculado, Techista, Calefaccion, Aire_Acondicionado, Electricidad_Iluminación, Pisos, Durlock, Aberturas, Pintura, Domotica, Seguridad y Vigilancia, Audio y Altavoz, Carpinteria, Herreria, Vidrieria, Marmoleria, Terminaciones, Proveedores Tercerizados, Piletero, Riego, Paisajismo, Destapacion cañerias, Varios, Honorarios]]
16:33:09 Información -1.0 16:33:09 
Aviso Se ha completado la ejecución
```

Podrian ayudarme ! Gracias

Comment: Hola! Por como se muestra el log, será posible que `rubro` también esté en un array y debas hacer `rubro[0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se origina en

```
var rubro = hojadatos.getActiveCell().getValues();
```

`getValues()` devuelve una matriz cuadrada, un objeto de tipo Array, que contiene un objeto tipo Array por cada fila, con un valor u objeto tipo Date por cada celda de la fila.

La solución simple podría ser usar `getValue()` en su lugar.

```
var rubro = hojadatos.getActiveCell().getValue();
```

ya que `getValue()` devuelve un valor o un objeto tipo Date correspondiente a la celda o celda superior izquierda del rango cuando este tiene más de una celda.

Si la celda contiene una fecha, `indexOf` devolverá -1 por lo que para que tu script sea robusto deberás implementar medidas para manejar este caso.

Comment: perfecto ruben ! muchas gracias por tu colaboracion